# Non T1 space with every convergent sequence is eventually constant

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms

I know that discrete space and cocountable space are $T1$ space with every convergent sequence is eventually constant (If we have a convergent sequence $(x_n),$ then $\exists\, n_0 \in N, \forall n\geq n_0, x_{n_0}=x_n ). $ Is there any example of a non T1 space with every convergent sequence is eventually constant? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be a non-T1 space, and let $a, b$ be two points such that every open set containing $a$ also contains $b$. Then, the sequence $\{a , b, a, b, ...\}$ is contained in every open set containing $a$, but it's not constant.

Comment: May I ask? So if X is a topology space with every convergent sequence is eventually constant, then X is T1?

Comment: Yes, that's the contrapositive of the statement

Comment: how do I guarantee that there are a and b such that every open set containing a and b ?

Comment: @MartinFirdaus This is just the negation of the definition of a $T_1$ space.

Comment: Let X={0,1} and \tau=\{X, empty set, {0}\}. A topological space (X, \tau) is not T1, but there is an open set {0} such that {0} doesn't contain 1.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you

Comment: If I choose a=1 and b=0, then every open set containing a also contains b.

Comment: @MartinFirdaus Indeed, if a space is US (every convergent sequence has a unique limit) then it is $T_1$. This is a classical fact. The cocountable topology is a $T_1$ and US space that is not $T_2$ (on an uncountable space).